# Automating MSI Install

Tags: windows-installer

I'm trying to automate the install of an MSI file. So far I have the command setup as so:

`msiexec /i myfile.msi PROPA="ANSWER" PROPB="ANSWER" PROPC="ANSWER"`

When I look at the resulting dialogs all the answers are filled in correctly. What I don't know how to do is automate the selecting of which modules to install. I have a huge log file I made with `/l*v log.txt` when I walked through this manually but I don't see any properties to set for the selected modules. How can I automate the selection of the modules to install?

Update:
`ADDLOCAL=ALL` will select everything but I am looking how to select only specific items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to run the installer interactively with the UI and select the required features for installation. At the same time you collect the log.

Then you copy the value of `ADDLOCAL` property from the log and pass it on the command-line. You can also set other properties if necessary.

With `/passive` option, MSI will show the installation progress but will not ask any question, neither will it show error messages. If reboot is required, it will automatically restart the system; to prevent it use `/norestart` option. See [Standard Installer Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.